# Copy *only* theme colors from one powerpoint presentation to another

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, themes, color-theme

I want to copy over the theme colors from one Powerpoint presentation to another.

The universal method seems to be to use the Format painter across both presentations, like explained e.g. on [this microsoft page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/powerpoint-help/use-the-color-scheme-of-another-slide-or-presentation-HP005192410.aspx):

1. Open both presentations, and then, on the Window menu, click Arrange All.
2. In both presentations, display the Slides tab in normal view.
3. Select the slide that has the color scheme you want to use.
4. Double-click Format Painter , click in the window of the second presentation, and then click each slide you want to apply the color scheme to.
   ...
5. Press ESC when finished to cancel Format Painter.
   NOTE   When you copy a slide's color scheme to another presentation, the color scheme becomes available in the Slide Design-Color Schemes task pane in the destination presentation.

**The problem is**, when I follow these instructions also the other formatting (like footer image etc.) gets applied to the slide(s). **I only want to theme colors to be copied over, not the other formatting.**

How can I do this (in Powerpoint 2007)?

Comment: are you adding the theme to existing documents or creating new presentations?

Comment: @James: existing documents

Answer (score 1):

Converting formats has always been challenging, at least for me.  I don't know that you are going to find a one step solution but here is how I would recommend executing:

- **Create a Master from the correct file.**

  View Tab >> Slide Master (under Master Views Section)

This brings up all the different slide types and allows you to configure them however you like.  It will take some time and effort to create the master.  **MAKE A BACKUP**  I suggest a working copy and a backup copy of the blank master...in the case of saving over the top of it on accident...

- **Convert old presentations**

This is where its messy.  Select everything in the old presentations and paste only the content

Chances are at this point you will have to do a little cleanup.

This definitely is not a one step process, but once it is organized it works very well.  Anytime you need to create a new presentation you simply open up the working copy of the master and save as.

Also worth mentioning that the more you can avoid custom formatting in the individual presentations the easier it will be to convert/modify your master in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this in Powerpoint 2010.

Open both files.

In the file with color scheme you want, ensure the color scheme name is findable. Copy one slide and paste it into the target file.

Then view the Slide Master view in the target file, and select your custom color scheme for your theme.  Then delete the slide that was copied in.